# Read and update a mongodb document by single call

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a collection called books.
When use browse a particular book, I get the book by id.
But I also want to increase the view count by 1 each time I read the doc.

I can use 2 commands: one to read and another to update the views counter by 1

Is there a wayy to do this by single command like findAndModify?

How to use that using CSharp driver?

```
Books:
{
  {
     "_id": "1"
     "title" : "Earth Day",
     "author" : "John ",
     "pages" : 212,
     "price" : 14.5,
     "views" : 1000
  },
  {
     "_id": "2"
     "title" : "The last voyage",
     "author" : "Bob",
     "pages" : 112,
     "price" : 10.5,
     "views" : 100
  }
}
```

I have this:

```
var query = Query.And(Query.EQ("_id", id));
            var sortBy = SortBy.Null;
            var update = Update.Inc("views", 1);
            var result = Books.FindAndModify(query, sortBy, update, true);
```

But how do I get the matching document back?

**EDIT:** I got it working..

```
return result.GetModifiedDocumentAs<T>();
```

**My question** is this call GetModifiedDocumentAs() will hit the database again?

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't hit the database again.

When in doubt about things like this, look at [the source](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/MongoDB.Driver/CommandResults/FindAndModifyResult.cs).   It shows that the `GetModifiedDocumentAs` method just accesses the resulting doc from the existing `Response` object and casts it to the requested type.